# Can I charge 18560 2000mAh (ish) Lithum Ion cell with 0.5 watt (ish) solar panel?

Tags: lithium-ion, solar-cell

As I understand it, peak charging current for a 18560 Lithium cell should be around 1C - which would be around 8.4 watts at 4.2 volts.

I'm planning to build a solar charging circuit for a cell as described, which will power a low power LED light. It's unlikely to ever be fully discharged - or only very occasionally, since the light will only be switched on when a sensor is activated, and will only see minimal use.

The idea is mainly ust to keep it "topped up" - which in terms of wattage should be be sufficiently achieved with a 0.5 watt solar panel. I'm just wondering if such a panel would actually provide enough current for it to ever fully charge - since at full whack it'll only be at around 0.12 A (or 1/16C of a 2000mAh cell) - if my brief calculations are correct? And what if the cell ever was fully discharged?

Comment: Welcome! What’s the open circuit voltage of the solar panel? You will most likely need either a DC-DC converter or at the very least some charge termination mechanism.

Comment: You can charge a lithium battery as slowly as you want. And can any solar panel do it depeds on the charger between solar panel and battery. What kind of solar panel it is and what kind of solar-input lithium battery charger you have?

Comment: @winny Thanks! I haven't settled on one yet (or any of the compenents for that matter), but the ones I'm looking at were listed as 2v or 5v. I'm thinking 5v would be better, because it could charge the battery (through charge controller) without the need to boost voltage? I'll link to parts in other comment.

Comment: @Justme This is the charge controller I was looking at: [link](https://www.lazada.com.ph//products/i3135524805-s15549228232.html?spm=a2o4l.cart.0.0.21b23e17dVtM1w&urlFlag=true)

Comment: I’d go for 2 V + boost converter. At 5 V, you _must_ charge terminate or the cell will hopefully just overheat and vent, worst case fiery rupture. To get useful energy from your panel, ideally you’d want MPPT. MPPC is usually good enough.

Comment: @tropical_bob That link should be added in to the question, not hidden
in comments. Also that's not a charger with solar input, it's with USB input. It will not work. Unless your solar panel has a solar to USB converter first. A solar panel should be loaded with a MPPT controller module, not with load directly.

Comment: @Justme Can't link the solar panel (because it's too long to comment), but it's 5v at 60mA (so a bit under what I was thinking)

Comment: I can't know if your 5V 60mA solar panel is a bare panel or has a MPPT controller so your question can't be answered due to lack of details. However, it might be answerable even without knowing this.

Comment: @Justme Oh, okay - sorry I'm new both here and to solar charging circuits :-) The input is listed as 4.5v - 8v so I assumed as long as the solar panel was outputting that, it'd be fine. Would it be alright with a 2v panel through boost converter to 5v, as suggested by @winny? Or would I be better of with a dedicated solar charging module (the ones I looked at didn't see come with a battery protection board though, if I understood the listings? - which is why I was looking at this one).

Comment: "As I understand it, peak charging current for a 18560 Lithium cell should be around 1C".  Unless a spec sheet says otherwise, the rule of thumb is 0.5 C charging for most Li-ion cells.

Answer (score 1):

The module has a charging current of 1A at 5V. It tries to pull 1A from supply.

Your panel is rated 5V 60mA.

The charger can't obviously pull 1A from a 60mA panel so it can't work.

Comment: Thanks! Theoretically possible though (?) just not with that module.

Comment: Anything that does not violate laws of physics is theoretically possible. But if you seek a module you can buy that does the things you want, it might not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum input power needed to charge a battery, it can be as low as 1mW and as high as your battery can handle. You can use the TP4056 module for that, even for low currents it has suitable effeciency.

However your solar charge controller may actually require a minimum input power, it depends entirely on its specific behaviour.

Therefore, I recommend the TP4056 as it works no matter the input current.